# MySQL - using result of Procedure in Trigger to Insert in new table

Tags: mysql-5.5, stored-procedures, trigger

I'm guessing I'm doing something that's prohibited by MySQL, but can't see what.

Basically, I have a set of tables that hold lists of things (`item name`, `item types`, `item groups` etc.), and I need to create a joining table to hold each of the ID's (e.g. `item_id`, `item_type_id`, `item_group_id`). At present there is no real relationship between the various lists. This table needs to be automatically populated each time I add a new `item`.

To get the matching entry, I need to use a `CASE` statement to match the first letters of the `item_name`, and get the relevant entry from the other table(s).

My plan is to have a set of Procedures (one for each table I need to join):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_get_item_type_id( item_name varchar(45) )
BEGIN
    SET @itemTypeID := (SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN LEFT(`item_name`,6)  = 'abcdef' THEN (SELECT t.`id` FROM `item_type` t WHERE t.`item_type_name` = 'type1')
            #repeats multiple times . . . 
            ELSE 0
            END AS `item_type_id`);
    SELECT @itemTypeID;        
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This works fine.

I then have a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_item_details
    AFTER INSERT
    ON `item` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET @itemId := new.`id`;
        CALL pr_get_item_type_id(new.`item_name`); #-->this Sets var @itemTypeID

        INSERT INTO `item_details` (`item_id`,`item_type_id`) VALUES (@itemID,@itemTypeID);
    END;    
$$    
DELIMITER ;
```

I then test this as follows:

```
INSERT INTO item (id,item_name) VALUES (1000,'abcdef')
```

But this results in:

```
Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
```

I tried setting the variable inside the trigger instead of the procedure:

```
SET @itemTypeID = (CALL pr_get_item_type_id(new.`item_name`));
```

But that didn't work either.

Is there a way to do this?

Example Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `item_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN', PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
CREATE TABLE `item_type` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `item_type_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN', PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
CREATE TABLE `item_details` (`item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`item_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`item_group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`item_type_id`,`item_group_id`));
INSERT INTO `item_type` (`item_type_name`) VALUES ('type1'),('type2');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the solution, and that is to convert the Procedure to a Function.

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION fn_get_item_type_id( item_name varchar(45) )
    RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
        RETURN (SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN LEFT(`item_name`,6)  = 'abcdef' THEN (SELECT t.`id` FROM `item_type` t WHERE t.`item_type_name` = 'type1')
            ELSE 0
            END AS `item_type_id`);
    $$
DELIMITER ;
```

From there I can simply Select it into a variable in the Trigger.

Comment: It's enough to delete `SELECT @itemTypeID;` statement from procedure code.